# PHP regexp to parse word xml

Tags: php, regex

I want to parse word-xml file with regexp and I need to replace the following code by another.

```
<w:p w:rsidP="001765FC" w:rsidRDefault="00E23FC0" w:rsidR="00EE5514">
    <w:sdt>
        <w:sdtPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:id w:val="491610033"/>
            <w:placeholder>
                <w:docPart w:val="A191284B5DB84C2A9DF7CC7D47F0B5AC"/>
            </w:placeholder>
            <w:temporary/>
            <w:showingPlcHdr/>
        </w:sdtPr>
        <w:sdtEndPr/>
        <w:sdtContent>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00EE5514" w:rsidRPr="00DC6564">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>[Стоимость]</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:sdtContent>
    </w:sdt>
</w:p>
```

I think it is possible to achieve with regexp, but I fail to overcome regexp's bottleneck.
I made somethins like:

```
<w:p(.*)>(\s*((.*)\[Стоимость\](.*))\s*)<\/w:p>
```

https://regex101.com/r/zN9lD0/4

But it is wrong regexp.
I need to find any string:

```
<w:p + ANY_TEXT + [TAG_NAME] + ANYTEXT + /w:p>
```

TAG_NAME is 'Стоимость' in my example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = "/<w:p.*?\[(.*?)\].*?<\/w:p>/gs";
```

**DEMO**: https://regex101.com/r/zN9lD0/6

Comment: Update:
https://regex101.com/r/zN9lD0/8
Needed negative lookahead, to separate tags:
<w:sdt></w:sdt>
<w:sdt></w:sdt>

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest agains trying to use regular expressions for XML. If at all possible, you should manipulate XML on a structured basis, for example using a DOM representation and getElementsByTagName to find the `<w:p>` elements, or using XSLT. A working XSLT solution (which is overkill for the task at hand, but should be seriously considered as soon as requirements start getting more complex) looks like this:

```
<?php
$doc_string = <<<END
<w:doc xmlns:w="http://example.org/w">
Before
<w:p w:rsidP="001765FC" w:rsidRDefault="00E23FC0" w:rsidR="00EE5514">
    <w:sdt>
        <w:sdtPr>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:id w:val="491610033"/>
            <w:placeholder>
                <w:docPart w:val="A191284B5DB84C2A9DF7CC7D47F0B5AC"/>
            </w:placeholder>
            <w:temporary/>
            <w:showingPlcHdr/>
        </w:sdtPr>
        <w:sdtEndPr/>
        <w:sdtContent>
            <w:r w:rsidR="00EE5514" w:rsidRPr="00DC6564">
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>[EXAMPLE]</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:sdtContent>
    </w:sdt>
</w:p>
After
</w:doc>
END;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($doc_string);

$stylesheet = new DOMDocument();
$stylesheet->loadXML(
"<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
    xmlns:w='http://example.org/w'>
  <!-- default: pass everything -->
  <xsl:template match='@*|node()'>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- special case: replace certain blocks -->
  <xsl:template match=\"w:p[//w:t[string(.)='[EXAMPLE]']]\">
    <b>Put your replacement here</b>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>"
);

$processor = new XSLTProcessor();
$processor->importStylesheet($stylesheet);
echo $processor->transformToXML($doc);
?>
```

This does not use any word-xml specific tools, just standard XML/XSLT libraries as provided by PHP 5 by default.

Comment: I searched for any tool to proccess word-xml, but didn't find any worked. so as I need to search and replace the only one type of expression I guess it is ok to use regex.

Comment: downvoter: please consider reverting your downvote as a working example is now provided.